# How to modify the css for reactjs-dropdown-component?

Tags: css, reactjs, drop-down-menu

**Goal**

I need to modify the CSS for the reactjs-dropdown-component.

**Background/Overview**

I've downloaded the dropdown, imported it, and have it fully operational in react. However, I'm fairly new to coding and haven't yet been in a situation where I need to do significant styling to a downloaded component. Do I just recreate the stylesheet for it and import it?

The css for this component is in this Github repo: https://github.com/dbilgili/Custom-ReactJS-Dropdown-Components/blob/master/src/styles/stylus/dropdown.styl

The instructions I followed for downloading/using this dropdown are here: https://github.com/dbilgili/Custom-ReactJS-Dropdown-Components

**I'm not sure that it's necessary but here is code where I'm using the dropdown**

```
import React from 'react';
import './EventContainer.css';
import { Dropdown } from 'reactjs-dropdown-component';
import { dining } from './EventContainerIcons.js';

class EventContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state =  {
      ...props.event,
      activityIcon: [
          {
            id: 0,
            title: <img src={dining} width="64" height="64" alt="dining icon" />,
            selected: false,
            key: 'activityIcon'
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            title: 'Orange',
            selected: false,
            key: 'activityIcon'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: 'Strawberry',
            selected: false,
            key: 'activityIcon'
          }
        ],
    };
  }

  handleTypeChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      type: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleTimeChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      time: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleSummaryChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      summary: e.target.value
    })
  }

  handleNotesChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      notes: e.target.value
    })
  }

  resetThenSet = (id, key) => {
  let temp = this.state[key];
  temp.forEach(item => (item.selected = false));
  temp[id].selected = true;
  this.setState({
    [key]: temp
  });
};

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="eventContainer-flex">
        <Dropdown
          title="Event Type"
          list={this.state.activityIcon}
          resetThenSet={this.resetThenSet}
        />
        <div>
          <input
            className="time-input-styling"
            type="time"
            value={this.state.time}
            onChange={this.handleTimeChange}/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea
            className="textarea-styling"
            /*placeholder="Write summary here"*/
            value={this.state.summary}
            onChange={this.handleSummaryChange}
            cols={60}
            rows={3} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea
            className="textarea-styling"
            /*placeholder="Write notes here"*/
            value={this.state.notes}
            onChange={this.handleNotesChange}
            cols={30}
            rows={3} />
          </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default EventContainer;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation, they alreayd said it:

> Refer to the following styling file for overriding the default styles.
>   You can create your own styling file with the same class names in
>   order to do your custom styling.

So, you have to create your css file, with the classes and override the classes you want.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the newb question. The thought process wasn't intuitive for me as I would've expected to need to add the css tags directly into the component's HTML tags.

Comment: Relax, but try this way and if not resolve, come back here.

Comment: I have not been successful. I recreated the css from the repo and imported it into the js file. I've tried adding the classNames and making adjustments to the css doc but nothing happens.